# display dynamic number of divs in a gallery view to fit in a container using css flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a structure like below for a video call application like zoom

```html
<div class="container" style="width:1000px;height:800px">
   <div class="item"></div>
   ...
</div>
```

number of items can be any number from 1 to 20

I need to show the `item`s in a gallery mode and set their size automatically to fit in the parent.

for example like below table (it doesn't matter the exact match with below as long as it looks good)

```
1 > full page
2 > 50% 50% 1 row
3 > 33% 33% 33% in 1 row
4 > 50% 50% in 2 rows
...
20 > 25% 25% 25% 25% in 5 rows
```

Like zoom video call gallery

I tried below but doesn't show properly

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  width: max-content // auto
  height: auto
}
```

Comment: You'll need JS to count the number of items first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the `item` dynamically then styles will be applied if there is only single `item` it takes `100%` when 2 `item` 50% 50% ..... and so on

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item{
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 1 0 22%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="width:1000px;height:800px">
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```